# Get a string value out of a thread

Tags: android, string, multithreading, amazon-dynamodb

I have a `String` variable, and I set it's value inside a thread, since it's using a netwok operation.

How can I access the values stored in the `Strings`?

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Initialize AWS DynamoDB Client
public static AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient;
public static DynamoDBMapper mapper;
public static Aqua aqua;

// App details
public static String a = "A";
public static String b;
public static Boolean c;
public static String d;
public static String e;
public static String f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "******", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.**** // Region
    );

    // Initialize AWS DynamoDB
    ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
    mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Get app details
                aqua = mapper.load(Aqua.class, a);
                b = aqua.getB();
                c = aqua.getC();
                d = aqua.getD();
                e = aqua.getE();
                f = aqua.getF();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ExecutorService` and submit `Callable` (below assumes you want the data that is stored inside b,c,d,e,f):

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<String[]> future = exec.submit(new Callable<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public String[] call() {
        try {
            // Get app details
            aqua = mapper.load(Aqua.class, a);
            b = aqua.getB();
            c = aqua.getC();
            d = aqua.getD();
            e = aqua.getE();
            f = aqua.getF();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return new String[] {b, c, d, e, f};
    }
});
// ... b will be at value[0], c at value[1]
String[] value = future.get();
```

Comment: There are problems with this code. For the first line (`Executors exec = ...`) I've added `(Executors)` before `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`, and it solved the error I got for it. For the second line, in the word `submit`, it says `Cannot resolve method 'submit(anonymous java.util.concurrent.Callable<java.lang.String>)'`. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Thanks, I'll run the code in a minute. Do I have to write the whole code block for every `String`?

Comment: No, I don't know where you have the strings, you could return a String[] with all the values.

Comment: OK, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the string globally in your Activity/Fragment. This way you can acces it from everywhere.

You could also use `handler.sendMessage(message);` with your String as message to send it whenever your Thread has finished or whenever you want to. You can then retrieve your String int

```
protected Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String status = (String) msg.obj;
        Log.i("Got a new message", "MESSAGE: "+status);
    }
};
```

Hope it helps :)